# Mysterious cosmetic Visual Studio Editor issue

Tags: visual-studio, ide

In the Visual Studio code editor, I sometimes have an extraneous mark on the white background. It's a short diagonal slash, one pixel wide. If I scroll up and down, the mark remains in the same place, more or less as if it was a scratch on the screen.

It's sometimes there, and sometimes not. I don't know how to make it appear or disappear. I believe it migrated from one computer to another when I changed machines (separate install of VS). It doesn't seem to interact with content at all.

This is the sort of thing I would not believe possible if I had not seen it. Anyone have any ideas on what could cause it?

Comment: How can you have a diagonal line if it's only one pixel wide?  Wouldn't that be a vertical line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think I've ever used a version of Visual Studio that drew the background of the code editor correctly 100% of the time.  I've seen the diagonal line and many variations of it.  It's almost certainly a VS bug.

Answer (score 1):

umm, a scratch on the screen, that perhaps you just fail to see sometimes?

Answer (score 1):

If you minimize then maximize Visual Studio and the mark disappears then it was probably a painting bug.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a separate install of VS.net using the same media?  Maybe the installation is somehow damaged.

Or maybe you have another program installed that VS.net doesn't play well with.

Answer (score 0):

If the two machines had the same video card, I'd suggest maybe a video driver issue. I remember a long time ago I had one card with a driver who's floodfill function would leak all over the desktop for one of my applications.